# TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise

After successfully implementing the gapi client in my Angular 2 app, I am now encounter an issue where my http object is undefined and I am not sure why.

Below is the code:
    constructor(private http: Http )  {}

```
initGmailApi() {

gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess().then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    const auth_code = resp.code;

    const body = {'AuthCode': auth_code};
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/startgmail', body,  headers).subscribe(
    (Response) => {
        console.log(Response);
    }
    );
});
}
```

Basically what I am doing is requesting a permission from the user to access his gmail account and when I have a response I would like to pass some data received to my backend server.

If I am using this.http outside the "then" clause then the http method works fine however this create another issue where the "auth_code" value is not recognized.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have a function : `function(resp)` which is changing your `this` the one you expect from the class. Use arrow function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to reference `this` within the callback, don't use `function() {}`

Use instead arrow functions:

```
then((resp) => {
```